# How to call async function inside a onClick (Button Click)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to javascript and I am trying to create the following:

I have a search form for flights and after a user clicks Search, the user immediately gets the results.

I want to change this process.
When a user fills the search form and clicks Search I want a POPUP screen to show with the Terms and conditions with a button "I understand". The results of the search will be shown only if the user clicks the button "I understand" in the POPUP.

I am trying to use await and async but I have no success still..

Here is the main code:

```
export function initSearchButtonOnClick() {
  $("#search-button").on("click", function (e) {
    activateLoadingOverlay2() // POPUP window Tearms & Condition


    // the code down needs to happen only after the user click the button "I understand" in the POPUP window.
    console.log("blerdii");

    e.preventDefault();
    switch (flightType) {
      case "rt":
      case "ow":
        if (
          $("#from-destination")[0].reportValidity() &&
          $("#to-destination")[0].reportValidity()
        ) {
          const fromDestination = $("#from-destination")
            .val() 
    More code below
```

Comment: I don't see any await and async in the code snippet that you pasted. Can you paste the actual code snippet?

Comment: You should add the data loading logic inside terms and condition button/checkbox click. No need to load the data at start when terms and conditions are not even accepted/nonaccepted.

Comment: Given the description of your goal of simply showing a dismissible modal, I don't see the point of using async/await.

Comment: Sweetalert2 could be used or any other modal dialog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

javascript is asynchrone and mono-thread. Forget about `await` and `async`.

From your popup HTML template, you have to bind a function when the user click  on the button "I understand". That all.

Your function `activateLoadingOverlay2()` should register an event listener of the "I understand" button to do what you want.